# where is the subject?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, conjugations, imperative-sentences

I have this sentence :

> Today's lecture will spark a lot of discussion, and I just want to let you know that I welcome it, so please feel free to jump in.

I have three questions:

1. Where is the subject of the verb "feel"?
2. If there is no subject, then it must be "felt", right?
3. What does "jump in" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implied subject is **you** (whoever is being addressed), as is commonly the case in commands, requests, invitations, etc.

> [You] feel free to jump in.
>    [You] step this way, sir.
>    [You] go away!

---

*Jump in* (or common alternatives such as *pitch in, dive in, leap in,* etc.) simply means *become completely [metaphorically] immersed in the discussion, and **participate, actively contribute, say something**.*

Answer (score 2):

The phrase is using the [imperative mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood), which is the mood used for requests or commands (among other cases).
The imperative mood is a particular mood, since it is used only for *you*; that is the reason why the subject is not explicit: It is always *you*.

To form the imperative mood, take the sentence in the indicative mood (simple present), and remove the subject; from "You eat onions on Saturdays." you get "Eat onions on Saturdays."
"Felt free to jump in" is wrong; the correct one is "feel free to jump in."

"Jump in" has two meanings:

- To interrupt a conversation
- To start to do something very quickly without spending a long time thinking first

In your case, the meaning is the second one.